# Al hacer web scraping me salen solo unos pocos items habiendo muchos más

Tags: nodejs, scraping, puppeteer

Al hacer scraping con puppeteer y cheerio a una web me saca todos los items pero pero la mayoria están vacios y las imagenes me pone undefined excepto unos pocos que los saca bien como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que utilizo: ..............................................

```
(async () => {
try {
  
 const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
  puppeteer2.use(StealthPlugin())
    const browser = await puppeteer2.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      headless: true,  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
   
          '--user-agent=' + USER_AGENT + '']
         
  });
      
    const page = await browser.newPage({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto('https://es.wallapop.com/search?keywords=' , { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
 

   const body = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.querySelector('body').innerHTML;
  });

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    const pageItems = $('.ItemCardList__item .ng-star-inserted' ).toArray()
  
      .map(item => {
          const $item = $(item);

          return {
           
              //  id: $item.attr('data-adid'), c10420p([^i]*)\/
              id: uuid.v4(),
              title: $item.find('.ItemCard__info').text(),
              link: "https://es.wallapop.com/item/",
              image: $item.find(".w-100").attr('src'),
              price: $item.find('.ItemCard__price').text().replace(/[_\W]+/g, ""),
              empresa: "wallapop",
         
          };
      });
  
      const allItems = items.concat(pageItems);
      console.log(pageItems.length,'items retrieved', allItems.length, 'acumulat  ed');
```

Comment: Quizá el *wait* que haces no es suficiente para esperar a que las imágenes se muestren.

Comment: he probado con varios wait pero nada, cual sugieres?

Comment: Has probado con *await page.waitForTimeout(10000)* inmediatamente después del *goto*. He puesto 10 segundos pero puedes ir afinando

Comment: Sigue igual, he puesto hasta un minuto..

Answer (score 0):

usando plain puppeteer y sin cheerio funciona

```
 const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector(".ItemCard__info");
  const items = await page.$$eval(".ItemCardList__item", els =>
    els.map(e => ({
      title: e.querySelector(".ItemCard__info").textContent.trim(),
      img: e.querySelector("img").getAttribute("src"),
      price: e.querySelector(".ItemCard__price").textContent.trim(),
    }))
  );
  console.log(items);
  console.log(items.length); // => 40
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```